# Jenkins Execute Shell task fails with stty: when specifying an output style, modes may not be set /dev/tty: No such device or address

Tags: node.js, jenkins, cloudhub

I am facing this issue since last OS update.

I am deploying Mule app with the help of anypoint-cli runtime-mgr cmdlet.

Here is the sample code I am using for the deployment in Execite Shell task of Jenkins job.

```
export ANYPOINT_USERNAME=username@env 
ifexist="`anypoint-cli runtime-mgr cloudhub-application list|grep -iapplication-name|wc -l`" 
if [ $ifexist == 0 ] 
then
echo "Deploying the application ... " anypoint-cli runtime-mgr cloudhub-application deploy application-name application-artifact.zip 
else 
echo "Updating & ReDeploying the application ... " 
anypoint-cli runtime-mgr cloudhub-application modify application-name application-artifact.zip anypoint-cli runtime-mgr cloudhub-application start application-name 
fi
```

I am getting following error:

> [workspace] $ /bin/sh /tmp/jenkins72443737290339703.sh channel stopped
>   /bin/bash stty: when specifying an output style, modes may not be set
>   /usr/lib/node_modules/anypoint-cli/node_modules/readline-sync/lib/read.sh:
>   line 48: /dev/tty: No such device or address stty: standard input:
>   Inappropriate ioctl for device Build step 'Execute shell' marked build
>   as failure Finished: FAILURE

The Shell script runs perfectly fine when run from terminal. Not sure what is happening when it is running in background.

Has anybody faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because when you are copying files over ssh, the ssh session can't able to find the tty file when you run it through jenkins. Because tty will be available in interactive sessions. It won't be available for cron or likewise sessions. So that's why you are getting that error. You won't get that error when you do that in terminal. Here I am attaching some links to go through. Hope this helps.

https://superuser.com/questions/1087382/dev-tty-no-such-device-or-address-only-in-a-script

https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/6625-script-cron-error.html

Comment: I got the solution. It was problem with Jenkins 2.112 which is not able to handle the shell execution in background. I downgraded the Jenkins to 2.100 and issue is resolved.

Comment: may be these versions have changed the code of handling job sessions. Anyways you got your answer right. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use ansible shell module to execute anypoint-cli,So that jenkins can able to trigger ansible playbooks.

The CLI supports both interactive shell and standard CLI modes, and works with:

### Playbook:

- hosts: localhost
  user: ec2-user
  tasks:

  - name: Executing a remote command
    shell: anypoint-cli --username="{{USER}}" --password="{{PASS}}" exchange asset upload [options]  [filePath]